# What does it mean "main thread can dynamically grow its stack"

Tags: linux, stack, pthreads

On man page for pthread_attr_setstacksize
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html

`A thread's stack size is fixed at the time of thread creation. Only the main thread can dynamically grow its stack.`

my understanding on linux pthread, the main thread stack size is limited to `ulimit -s` value on main thread creating. Although it maps phy to virt on demand of stack usage, the size is not grow any more.

What does the dynamically grow mean here? Does it imply main thread stack size can grow exceed `ulimit -s`?

Comment: let's say default stack size for main thread in pthread_attr. I think this value for main thread is set to `ulimit -s`, right? and grow should mean this value can grow dynamically or actual stack size exceed it

Comment: without calling pthread_attr_setstacksize, the other thread has stack size set to `ulimit -s`. so you mean main thread default stack size is a smaller value and can grow to `ulimit -s`? and set stack size to 8gb doesn't mean allocated 8gb phy mem, just the virt size reservasion

Answer (score 2):

The value set by `ulimit -s` (aka `setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, ...)`), usually 8 MB by default, is the *maximum* stack size.  Initially, a much smaller amount of virtual memory will be allocated and mapped (perhaps just a few kb).  When the stack grows larger than the amount actually allocated, it triggers a page fault.  The kernel then compares the current usage with the maximum value set in the rlimit.  If the maximum has not been reached, the kernel allocates more pages of virtual memory and maps them into place, then returns control to the process; this is completely transparent.  If the maximum is reached, it kills the process with SIGSEGV.

It would be inefficient if the system had to reserve a full 8 MB of virtual memory for every process, when most will use far less.  By allocating it only as needed, you can still have hundreds of processes, each with an 8 MB stack limit, even if the machine has only (let's say) 64 MB of memory + swap total.  It's a form of [overcommitment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441364/what-is-the-purpose-of-memory-overcommitment-on-linux).

Also keep in mind that a process can call `setrlimit` itself at run time and increase its own maximum stack size, so long as nothing else has been mapped into that address space.  The main thread's stack is traditionally located near the top of virtual memory, with everything else near the bottom, so that there is a lot of free address space in between, and so increasing the maximum beyond its initial 8 MB limit is usually possible.  However, the stacks of other threads necessarily must be allocated elsewhere, and it is not really possible to ensure that there is a lot of free address space for them to grow into.

Comment: As I know, other threads also use `ulimit -s` as their max stack size and allocate pages on demand. if this is so called dynamic grow, then both main and other threads are doing this. And what is the value to get when calling pthread_attr_getstacksize? it's a dynamic number or fixed to `ulimit -s`? You mentioned other threads is not really possible to ensure the free space, but from mechanism perspective, I don't think man page is talking about this

Comment: Do you mean, if `ulimit -s` changed after process started, other threads still use the value when creating, but main thread will modify its stack size(can be read by pthread_attr_getstacksize) to new `ulimit -s`, and this procedure is called dynamic grow.