# Difference between getrlimit and /proc/self/maps

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stack

I want to find out the stack size of my process in C++ with Ubuntu 20.04 server. I have two procedures:

**First:** print `/proc/self/maps` and retrieve stack size from boundaries

```
int mapsfd = open("/proc/self/maps",O_RDONLY);
system("cat /dev/fd/3 | grep stack");
```

**Second:** `getrlimit()`

```
struct rlimit limit;
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &limit);
printf("Stack size = %ld\n", limit.rlim_cur);
```

First gives back: `7ffe17007000-7ffe17156000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]` --> stack size = 0x14F000 = **1372160 bytes**

Second gives back: **8388608 bytes**

Why are the results different? What is the difference between `/proc/self/maps` and `getrlimit()`?

Comment: Currently mapped stack, versus limit of stack?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719748/1548468) explains the difference you see.